# Fix noisy washing machine spin cycle

Tags: repair, washing-machine, noise, noise-reduction

I have a Whirlpool WWDC9440 Freestanding Washing Machine which I've had for 4 years. 
Recently (or gradually as I can't remember a step change) the spin cycle has become very noisy with the vibrations sounding like it's about to take off!
I bought sound dampening feet pads for it but hearing it again I think something needs repairing...

Here is a video so you can hear it:
https://photos.app.goo.gl/6k9NZ9Bvbt18uDFF9
It sounds like the noise is coming from something hitting the left side of the case.

And here you can see me wobbling the drum:
https://photos.app.goo.gl/uh9BtBSWrhwPwgYDA
The drum is easy to move left and right, is this the shock absorbers or the bearing?

Any ideas what the problem is?
What parts do I need to fix it?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like the bearing is worn.

It will need to be replaced but doing so will require quite a bit of work dismantling the washing machine to get at it.

Comment: here you can see me wobbling the drum https://photos.app.goo.gl/uh9BtBSWrhwPwgYDA still think it's the baring? Could it be the shock absorbers? The noise sounds like it's hitting the left outer case...